# JavaでJSONを使用してLocalのPostgreSQLサーバーにアクセスする

Tags: java, android, json

Android Studio4.0 を使用しています。
JavaでJSONをしようして自分のPCのLocalにインストールしている、
PostgreSQLサーバーにアクセスしてカラムデータを取り出したいです。
現在は以下の記述にしていますがいいうまくできません。
どの様に記述すればよいですか？

```
// 送信先URL
 //String strPostUrl = "http://192.168.100.20:8080/api/login/";
 String strPostUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/api/login/";
 String JSON = "{"updkbn", "ifkbn", "messagecode", "updtimesearch","sectionnosearch", "lastupdid","sectionno"}";

 // 認証
 HttpSendJSON httpSendJSON = new HttpSendJSON();
 String result = httpSendJSON.callPost(strPostUrl, JSON);
```

Comment: 出力されたエラーを質問本文に記載して下さい。

Comment: すみません。
ほかのErrorがいっぱいあって、Error文は別のものが出ています。
ただ、上記記述が文法がおかしいようで、String JSONの文は赤文字表記になっています。
その他、気になっているのがString strPostUrlの記述があっているか知りたいです。

Comment: 文字列内で「`"`」を使いたいときはその前すべてに「\」を付けて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
URLの方はどうでしょうか？
PCのLocalにPostgeSQLサーバーを入れているのですが。

Comment: まずはコンパイルエラーが出ないようにして下さい。次にプログラムを実行してエラーが出たら、それを質問本文に追記して下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
わかりました。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/297965